# Help with a Castle Active Record DeleteAll HQL String

Tags: .net, castle-activerecord

So I basically want to have a static method in my AR class to delete all records on a specified expression.  But apparently Castle Active Record doesnt have an overload for IQuery params (at least not the version I am using).

This is what I am "effectively" trying to acheive:

```
public static void Delete(string pAppIdentifier) {
  DeleteAll(new EqExpression("AppIdentifier", pAppIdentifier));
}
```

It is possible to use HQL (as one of the overloads for DeleteAll allows a where HQL string, but I really dont yet fully understand HQL and all its power and I was hoping one of my Stack Overflow peers could help me turn that example above into HQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DeleteAll(string.Format("AppIdentifier='{0}'", pAppIdentifier))
```

this is translated into:

```
session.Delete(string.Format("from {0} where {1}", type.Name, where));
```

BTW make sure that the pAppIdentifier parameter is safe, otherwise you'll have a potential SQL injection vulnerability.

This and other common questions in the [ActiveRecord wiki](http://using.castleproject.org/display/AR/FAQ).

Comment: is "where" in your translation simply "pAppIdentifier"?

Comment: Actually, what i mean to ask - is it:
session.Delete(string.Format("from {0} where AppIdentifier='{1}'", type.Name, pAppIdentifier));